# How did the Veil end up in the Ministry?

Tags: harry-potter

In Order of the Phoenix, we encounter the Veil in the Ministry's Department of Mysteries. With the nature of this artifact, it seems as though it would be, at best, very difficult to move. It also appears to be located very centrally within the Department of Mysteries.

Was the Department of Mysteries, and subsequently the entire Ministry, constructed around the Veil?

Comment: More likely, the Unspeakables constructed the archway as a tool to create/hold the veil.

Comment: @JoeryJV : You know, I always assumed that the Veil and the archway were inseparable; that the archway makes up the boundary of the Veil.

Comment: That is definately possible, but I still doubt that they constructed everything around the veil. Mostly because of the fact that it is so deep underground. I am basing this on nothing however, so i could be wrong.

Comment: Thing is, the way it looks is different between movie and book. In the Movie, it's a tall and narrow stone archway filled with some kind of weird, misty substance. In the book the archway is described as ancient and crumbling, and hung over it is some kind of tattered black curtain. The description in the book implies that the curtain can be removed from the archway.